# Running UI tests with Chrome Driver in GitLab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, gitlab, continuous-integration

I run into issue when trying to run unit tests for a website using ChromeDriver. Here is the stack trace from job log:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:37329/
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
StackTrace:    at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory)
   at ScamTeamWebsiteTests.Tests.Setup() in /builds/kostyabek/ScamTeamWebsiteTests/ScamTeamWebsiteTests/WebSiteTests.cs:line 19
```

.yml file contents

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  projFolder: "ScamTeamWebsiteTests"
  projName: "ScamTeamWebsiteTests.csproj"

before_script:
  - "apt-get update -qy"
  - "apt-get -y install zip unzip"
  - "cd ${projFolder}"
  - "wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/102.0.5005.27/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
  - "unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d '/home/kostyabek'"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "dotnet build"

unit-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    "dotnet test ${projName}"
```

Basically, I have no idea what to do with it. I am relatively new to both CI/CD pipelines and Selenium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run an instance of selenium chrome with your unit-test stage. Downloading chromedriver may be unnecessary.

```
unit-test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest 
  script:
    - dotnet test ${projName}
```

You will need to configure your test suite to connect to the remote web driver at `http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub`, when running in the CI test environment.

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#accessing-the-services